# Algorithm for forming adjacency list with nested neighbors

Tags: c++, graph, language-agnostic, adjacency-list

I'm having a hard time coming up with a good algorithm for forming the adjacency list when given a list of synonyms.

The list of synonyms are provided as a vector of vectors. The inner vector is size 2 and consists of 2 words that are synonymous.

e.g.,

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> synonyms{{"joy", "happy"}, {"happy", 
"ecstatic"}, {"cheerful, ecstatic"}, {"big", "giant"}, {"giant", "gigantic"}};
```

So here we have 2 sets of synonymous words: `{joy, happy, ecstatic, cheerful}` and `{big, giant, gigantic}`

I want to create an adjacency list from the list of edge using an `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>`. The value is a `set` because the neighbors need to be sorted. Alternatively, the value could be a vector, and then we would sort the vector in the end. 
What is the best way make this adjacency list given the edges?

For this adjacency list, I would like an entry for each word. So in the above example, I would have 7 entries. And for each entry, I would like to map it to all the words it's synonymous with. Something like:

```
{happy} -> {cheerful, ecstatic, joy}
{joy} -> {cheerful, ecstatic, happy}
{ecstatic} -> {cheerful, happy, joy}
{cheerful} -> {ecstatic, happy, joy}
{giant} -> {big, gigantic}
{big} -> {giant, gigantic}
{gigantic} -> {big, giant}
```

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yes, sorry I forgot to include that. I just put in a paragraph at the end. Does that clarify things?

Comment: So the input is specified to be a `vector<vector<string>>`, but it's effectively a pair since the inner vector can only have 2 elements.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Actually, you could just assume it's a pair if that makes it easier. I'm much more interested in the algorithm than how things are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Assume two isolated neighborhoods of words, **`Na`** and **`Nb`**. Each word in a neighborhood knows all other words in the neighborhood (synonyms). Then, we specify that a word from **`Na`**, called `Wa`, and a word from **`Nb`**, called `Wb` are declared synonyms. We must have `Wa` and every neighbor of `Wa` (i.e., each word in **`Na`**) add `Wb` and every neighbor of `Wb` (i.e., each word in **`Nb`**) to its list of neighbors (synonyms). And we must have each word in **`Nb`** add each word in **`Na`** to its list of neighbors (synonyms).

At the end of this operation, all words know of all other words in the new combined neighborhood, which makes this new neighborhood a valid input for another iteration of the above algorithm.

A single word with no synonyms added yet is a neighborhood of 1, which makes it a valid input to the algorithm.

Don't think of combining words. Think of combining neighborhoods. Each word maps to its full neighborhood to start. This makes cramming neighborhoods together easier. Later we can remove each word from its own neighborhood.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> al;

for (auto const & syns : synonyms)
  for (auto const & word : syns)
  {
    al[word].insert(word);
    for (auto const & syn : syns)
    {
      al[syn].insert(syn);
      if (word != syn)
      {
        // add the entire neighborhood of word to
        // the entire neighborhood of syn, and vice versa
        for (auto const & neighbor_word : al[word])
          for (auto const & neighbor_syn : al[syn])
          {
            al[child_word].insert(child_syn);
            al[child_syn].insert(child_word);
          }
      }
    }
  }

// remove each word's mapping to itself as a synonym:
for (auto & words : al)
  words.second.erase(words.first);
```

Messy as heck, and I don't want to evaluate the complexity, but gets the job done. I think?

Pending peer review...